# Magento site migration

Tags: magento

I have a website "mystore.com" running on rackspace. I want to migrate this site to hostgator account on which my primary domain is "primary.com". I created an addon domain on hostgator with the same name as "mystore.com". At this stage, I could access the site as "`primary.com/mystore.com`".

But after I installed magento on this addon, it is redirecting to the original "mystore.com" on rackspace. I was hoping to set everything up on my addon domain and then point the name servers to it. Is this possible?

Comment: You can find a nice walk-through on the magento site, http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server , keep in mind, you may need to change the site url in the database so that you do not get redirected back to the original, fire up phpMyadmin or some tool and do a search for the domain in one of the core tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Magento stores domain name in database, you would need to run the following queries against your database to update the domain path.

`UPDATE core_config_data set value='http://mystore.com' where value='http://primary.com'`

and similarly for Secure URL

`UPDATE core_config_data set value='https://mystore.com' where value='https://primary.com'`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Database**
Edit table **core_config_data**
change values for path **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url**
to **http://www.mystore.com/**

**Step 2: Clear Cache, Index and Session**

**Step 3: Check your site**

PS: Make sure you have changed the **app\etc\local.xml** file with database details